# Excel macro formula adding quotes in formula causing vlookup to not work

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to add a formula to a cell. The macro is adding quotations around the cell range, which causes the cell to return the #name error.

This is the code in the macro

```
Cells(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Contracts!A7:D30,3,FALSE)"
```

This is what the code returns in Excel after executing the macro.

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,Contracts!'A7':'D30',3,FALSE)
```

Note that #name error disappears and the formula works, after I remove the quotations around the cell A7 and D30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix RC and A1 style references in the same formula.  Pick one and stick to it.

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Contracts!R7C1:R30C4,3,FALSE)"
```

will work

Answer (score 1):

The RC[-2] seems to be the problem. When I replaced that with a normal cell reference the macro didn't put quotes around the A7 and D30.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by mixing RC notation (FormulaR1C1) and A1. Have you tried:

```
Cells(1, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],""Contracts!A7:D30"",3,FALSE)"
```

? That should work.